# Redirigir a una sección de la pagina Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Saludos lo que estoy intentando hacer es redirigir a una sección de la pagina web en Angular, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
<div name="citasVigentes" id="citasVigentesData" class="content-target">
</div>
```

a esta parte es a la que quiero redireccionar.
Estoy intentando hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
<a id="citasVigentesExecute" [routerLink]="['citasVigentesData']">redirige a citas vigentes</a>
```

en html puro si funciona pero en angular no me redirige a esta sección de la pagina, espero me ayuden muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si la sección ya existe en tu página y quieres hacer scroll hasta dicha sección puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera. Sin usar angular ni javascript.

En el atributo `href` puedes poner el `id` de tu sección y cuando se clique el link este hará scroll hacia la sección con ese `id`.

Tienes que poner la `#` para hacer referencia al id de la sección.

```css
.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<a id="citasVigentesExecute" href="#citasVigentesData">redirige a citas vigentes</a>
<div class="content"></div>
<div name="citasVigentes" id="citasVigentesData" class="content-target">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, consectetur laboriosam repellat possimus, placeat ullam autem animi consequatur rem enim, aliquid ex facilis reiciendis quaerat commodi voluptate debitis earum recusandae.
</div>
```